# Input saved to history

Tags: r

The applications I develop for my team often require input from the user to specify actions they want to perform.

Currently these users save both a history and their altered datasets.

From there our data scientist will then perform meta analysis on these 'experiments'. But, the problem is, **the user input is not saved to the work history**.

For example

```
someFunction<-function(){
    choices <- c('a','b','c')
    choice <- menu(choices)

    print('you chose ',choice)

}
```

What would be ideal is for the function to add the print statement to the history.

`someFunction()`

Comment: There is a function `savehistory(file = ".Rhistory")`.

Comment: Well, relying on interactive steps doesn't make it easy to make something reproducible. If they are creating a work history, why not just type a command like `someFunction("a")`? Is that really that much more difficult? Alternatively, don't rely on the default history mechanism if you are trying to save information. Maybe use a package specifically for logging.

Comment: Why not just generate a simple log file containing the prompt, user input, date and time, etc?

Comment: @MrFlick The problem is that i am working with non computer scientists, even the feat of getting them to use the current base amount of programming has been difficult. What i am requesting is what i believe to be a compromise of these two worlds.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the problem is that savehistory doesn't save user inputs from the menu function.